# ssd_inception_v2 is not supported. See `model_builder.py` for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm working on an object detection project. I followed [the instruction from Github.](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10?fbclid=IwAR36wdN6VAQ1lrOjvVCYPSEi1cOhAhwPDO0fUR-EqR8LRLLNoCDr8u3OyYM#1-install-anaconda-cuda-and-cudnn)

But I used a different model.

I run this command

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
```

The error is

```
ValueError: ssd_inception_v2 is not supported. See `model_builder.py` for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow
```

I don't know why. I tried to change the model version but still error.

Please guide me. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I already knew how to solve it. I used model which is support Tensorflow 1.*, but I build my program with Tensorflow 2.*. So, I changed the to use a model which support tensorflow 2.*

Comment: Can you tell me which model did you use? even I am facing a similar issue

Comment: which model did you use please?

Comment: If you already knew how to solve it, why did you asked the question?

Comment: I am using this tutorial: https://medium.com/geekculture/training-a-model-for-custom-object-detection-using-tensorflow-1-x-on-google-colab-564d3e62e9ef and when I run this command: `!python model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=/content/drive/MyDrive/customTF1/data/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config --model_dir=/content/drive/MyDrive/customTF1/training --num_train_steps=200000 --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 --alsologtostderr` I got the above mentioned error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

For those asking where to find v2 version of ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco trained models please visit and download appropriate model:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md